# IE11 doesn't send a form if cookie is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have a webform which has asking for some cookie settings:

```
par=Cookies.get('demo'); // => 'value'
```

Cokies are set after part1 of current Form  filled out.

If to fill Form1 and than to fill current Form everything works well however if I open a page directly by weblink with no Form1 was fillled out (cookie 'demo' is undefined) than Form is not submitting.

No errors, no message. Button is processing but data is not sending out. How to fix it?

THE ISSUE HAPPENS ON IE11 Only.

Comment: `par=Cookies.get('demo') || '';` The `|| ''` at the end defaults the value to an empty string if undefined.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thank you, it works in my case! Appreciate your support!

Comment: @ JM-AGMS, I suggest you to post your suggestion as an answer. @ J.First Coder, I can see that your issue was solved. So you can try to mark the answer for this thread when JM-AGMS post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

par=Cookies.get('demo') || ''; The || '' at the end defaults the value to an empty string if undefined. – JM-AGMS 12 hours ago